# Timed Out and NZEC on CodeChef Problem NUKES

Tags: java

While trying out the problem "Nuclear Reactors" , i'm getting the results on my computer ,but in CodeChef there is a timelimit of 0.2 secs and while submitting my answer i'm getting a TLE(time limit exceeded) error and in one test i'm getting wrong answer.
I don't have a clue what is causing this.
Any hints would be helpful.

Link :https://www.codechef.com/problems/NUKES

My code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FastReader fr = new FastReader();

        // I/P
        int a = fr.nextInt();
        int n = fr.nextInt();
        int k = fr.nextInt();

        // ARRAY TO STORE RESULT
        int react[] = new int[k];

        // ARRAY OF ZERO AND ONES
        int temp_one[]=new int[k];
        int temp_zero[]=new int[k];

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
            react[i] = 0;
            temp_zero[i]=react[i];
            temp_one[i]=1;
        }

        while (a != 0) {    // TO REPEAT TILL ALL (A) ARE USED
            int j = 0;

            while(react[j]>=n){     // CHECK(value in K>=A)
                react[j] = 0;
                j++;
            }
            react[j]++;

            if(Arrays.equals(react,temp_one)){ // CHECK(all K are filled)
                react=temp_zero;
            }
            a--;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            System.out.print(react[i]+" ");
        }
    }
    //////////////////// FAST IO //////////////////////
    static class FastReader{
        BufferedReader br;
        StringTokenizer st;

        public FastReader() {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        }

        String next() {
            while (st == null || !st.hasMoreElements()) {
                try {
                    st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return st.nextToken();
        }

        int nextInt() {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }

    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

[Results given by CodeChef](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVioV.png)

Comment: Are you looking for a more efficient algorithm? The problem may be that your computer can execute more operations per second than the judging computer, and thus it will be much faster for your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work for your algorithm.

```
int[] ret = new int[k];
for(int i = (int)(Math.log(a)/Math.log(n+1)); i >= 0; i--) {
    int val = (int)(a/Math.pow(n+1,i));
    a -= val*Math.pow(n+1,i);
    if (i < k) ret[i] = val;
}
```

`ret` is your return array.
It basically finds the base n+1 representation of a, which is the answer they want you to get. If you want more information on why it works, feel free to ask!

Comment: What was your approach towards the question and how did u formulate the above algorithm. ?

Comment: In terms of results , it is producing the correct results . I'm kinda dumbfounded on how to did it though 0_0

Comment: NEW UPDATE: In test number 8 , it is giving TLE(Time Limit Exceeded). Nonetheless would like to know your approach to the question

Comment: @Payas_2001 Sure! So a lot of it just comes from experience with these sorts of things, but what you notice is that when n is, for example, 6, you can add 6 particles to the chamber before it overflows to the second one, you can add 36 (6^2) to the chamber before it overflows to the third one, then 216 (6^3) and so on. This means you can figure out the highest chamber it will reach and start there. If you can only reach the third chamber, then each particle in the third chamber can be reached by using 6^(3-1) or 36 particles. You then divide `a` by 36 to see how many particles you can put in

Comment: the 3rd chamber. Then, you take what's left over and see how many you can fit into the second chamber, where each particle is worth 6^(2-1) or 6 particles. You divide what's left in `a` by 6, and that's the number of particles you can fit into that chamber. Whatever is left over in `a` is what you can fit into the first chamber. I realize it may be confusing, and if it is then the only way to really understand it is to get the connection between this and representing a in base n+1.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Payas_2001 Anytime!